# Using Regular expression to match string that not end with 's

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to use regex to match strings that not end with 's, I wrote a regex like this: `.*[^('s)$]$`, but it seems that this regex also cannot match a string that ends with a single s, like cats or dogs, can somebody help? thx

I am using `egrep`, I have tried like

```
^(?!.*'s$).*
```

or

```
.*(?<!ab)$
```

but it seems these not working well

Comment: `.*$(?<!'s)` or `^(?!.*'s$).*`, but most languages also support `.endswith` string methods, check your language API.

Comment: actually, I am using egrep, the command line in shell, and this answer seems not working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look-around assertions are traditionally not supported in `grep. You may be able to use`grep -v` here:

```
grep -v "'s$" file
```

`-v` option is used for inver-match which is used to return lines are those not matching any of the specified patterns.

---

However do note in in `gnu-grep` you can use experimental `-P` option to use advanced PCRE features such as lookahead and lookbehind assertions.

Comment: thx in advance, and now I have another question: what if I want to match a string contains a specific string like 'aa' but not end with 's ? It seems I cannot solve this problem with  -v  :(

Comment: You can use pipeline so `grep 'aa' file | grep -v "'s$"`